# How to display current localtime in 12hr format in ionic dateTime input

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, ionic-framework

**component:**

```
pickupTime: string = ’ ’

this.pickupTime = moment().format(‘LT’);

console.log(‘pickup TIme’, this.pickupTime);

 //display time in format 9:30 AM
```

or

```
pickupTime = new Date.toLocaleTimeString() //display time in format 9:30 AM
```

The time does not display in the pickupTime unless its formated in

```
toISOString() 
example: pickupTime = new Date.toISOString()
```

Comment: <ion-datetime formControlName=“pickUpTime” class=“input-box” displayFormat=“h:mm a” pickerFormat=“h:mm a” [(ngModel)]=“pickupTime” type=“time”>

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic framework, datetime values as a string uses the standardized ISO 8601 datetime format. To format the current datetime to specific timezone, you are recommended to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), an open source javascript library. Please refer to [this link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/#advanced-datetime-validation-and-manipulation) in the documentation.

```
 moment(new Date().toISOString()).locale('es').format();
```

Comment: thanks. The time now displays in the dateTime input.However my server api now response with a error message that the time is required. This problem is the form is not recognizing the value in the dateTime input when submitted. I can also see the time value in the form object  before its submitted.  
pickUpTime: "2018-04-08T09:00:52-04:00"

Comment: @d-shall I am not sure if it is a formatting problem but if it is, try using Valid datetime formats like: moment(new Date().toISOString()).locale('es').format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm');

Comment: Ionic dateTime does not display in the format  this.pickupTime = moment(new Date().toISOString()).locale('es').format('h:mm a');
 <ion-datetime formControlName="pickUpTime" class="input-box"  displayFormat="h:mm a" pickerFormat="h:mm a" [(ngModel)]="pickupTime" type="text"></ion-datetime>